# C pass macro as parameter pointer

Tags: arrays, c, macros

I have a function called ADS_Transmit, declared as follows

```
void ADS_Transmit(uint8_t* data, uint16_t size);
```

The function is supposed to take arrays of uint8_t as parameter, but in some conditions, I'd like to send macros when calling the function. Like this

```
#define ADS_CMD_RST 0x06U
ADS_Transmit(ADS_CMD_RST, 1); // Does not work
uint8_t data = ADS_CMD_RST;
ADS_Transmit(&data, 1); // Works
```

Now perhaps obvious to many, sending the macro in the parameter doesn't work, since the function will use what's on register 0x06.
But is there a way that I could send the macro in the parameter without changing the function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A macro represents a piece of text. A bunch of source code characters.

Comment: That's right. So I presume that it's not possible to do it in the way I want. I could just as well change the parameter of the function and work around it. Just wanted to make sure I understood why it doesnt work. Thanks!

Comment: No, it just doesn't make sense to talk about macros in this context. `ADS_CMD_RST` represents characters that make up the number 0x06U. So you should be asking "how do I send a number to a function that expect an address without storing the number in a variable and sending the address of the variable". You actually can do that, macros only muddle the water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
ADS_Transmit(&(uint8_t){ADS_CMD_RST}, 1);
```

This creates a temporary `uint8_t` variable, initialized with the value `ADS_CMD_RST`, and passes its address to `ADS_Transmit`.

Note that if `ADS_Transmit` modifies the memory pointed to by the first argument, you won't be able to access the updated values.

Comment: Nice! This is what I was looking for. My best effort was writing ADS_Transmit((uint8_t) &ADS_CMD_RST, 1) but that didn't work. Thank you for the help, this works!

Comment: Follow up question. If I'd like to use this method and send 2 bytes. Is there a nice way to do it? This is what I'm trying to do ADS_Transmit(&(uint8_t){(0x16U<<8)|(0x10U)}), though  only the first 8 bits are being sent in this case

Comment: @Krippkrupp: Yep, use a compound literal of array type.  `ADS_Transmit((uint8_t[]){0x10U, 0x16U}, 2);`

Comment: Now that I see it, perhaps it should've been obvious! This should also work for transmitting one byte as well, i.e ADS_Transmit((uint8_t[]){0x10U},1);
Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me out!